# I need help in a bit complicated sql query

Tags: sql

I have two tables:

```
students (name, test_code, grade)
Tests    (test_code, subject, part)
```

there are 2 parts : a  and b.

I would like to have a query that pulls the names of all students who have passed the part a (more than 50), but not part b (less than 50).

The result should be somthing like that:

```
John - chemistry part a 70
                 part b 23
```

many thanks, hope I am understood... I am a newbie to sql...
I think there should be a group by for name but again its a bit complicated for me... 
so any help would  be appreciated!
Thanks..

Comment: Nice. What have you already tried?

Comment: Please show sample input table data.

Comment: You need a third table, a junction table, that establishes the many-to-many relationship between students and tests.

Comment: the tables are a bit uncomfortably set up

Answer (score 0):

Your table structure leaves a lot to be desired, but if you have to use what you have, then this should work:

```
SELECT pass.name, pass.subject, pass.part, pass.grade, fail.part, fail.grade
FROM
(SELECT a.name, b.subject, b.part, a.grade
FROM Students a
INNER JOIN Tests b ON a.test_code = b.test_code AND b.part = 'a' AND a.grade > 50) pass
INNER JOIN (SELECT a.name, b.subject, b.part, a.grade
            FROM Students a
            INNER JOIN Tests b ON a.test_code = b.test_code AND b.part = 'b' 
                               AND a.grade < 50) fail on pass.name = fail.name
```

Otherwise, if you do have some flexibility, I would suggest this table structure:

```
students (id, name) PRIMARY KEY (id)
results  (studentid, test_code, grade) PRIMARY KEY (student_id, test_code)
Tests    (test_code, subject, part) PRIMARY KEY (test_code)
```

This gives you several benefits including having only have 1 row per individual student in your students table and also the ability to have more than 1 student with the same name (the id is unique)

Answer (score 0):

If this table structure is a given, then you can select as follows:

First select distinct combinations of student and subject, then find out testcodes for this subject and part a and b respectively, then find the grades for this student and this test code.

```
SELECT 
    student_subject.name,
    student_subject.subject,
    part_a.grade AS grade_a,
    part_b.grade AS grade_b
FROM ( 
    SELECT DISTINCT s.name, t.subject
    FROM students s
    JOIN tests t ON s.test_code = t.test_code ) AS student_subject
LEFT JOIN 
    tests testcode_a 
    ON testcode_a.part = 'a' 
    AND testcode_a.subject = student_subject.subject
LEFT JOIN 
    tests testcode_b 
    ON testcode_b.part = 'b'
    AND testcode_b.subject = student_subject.subject
LEFT JOIN 
    students part_a 
    ON part_a.test_code = testcode_a.test_code
LEFT JOIN 
    students part_b 
    ON part_b.test_code = testcode_b.test_code
WHERE 
    part_a.grade >= 55 AND part_b.grade < 55
```

[SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/67bb0b/15)

You'll be better off if you rethink the table model and normalize it, though.